# How to statically link to an existing rlib?

Tags: rust

I have two independently created `libsomelibrary.rlib` files at `/path/to/deps/debug/` and `/path/to/deps/release/` directories. I also have a project in the `/path/to/myproject/` directory which needs to link statically to `libsomelibrary.rlib`.

How can I specify in Cargo.toml (or elsewhere) the references to those .rlibs?

I have tried to add `somelibrary` under `[dependencies]` in Cargo.toml. using a build.rs to specify the search path and file name:

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=somelib");
println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=/path/to/deps/debug/");
```

then in Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
build = "build.rs"
links = "somelibrary"
```

but I still get linkage errors.

Comment: What the heck are you even trying to do? Why do you have arbitrary rlibs lying around that aren't part of an existing crate?

Comment: I want to distribute self-contained .rlibs without having to publish the source code.

Comment: I thought so. You are fighting an uphill battle: [Can libraries be distributed as a binary, so the end user cannot see the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27999559/155423)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I get your point after reading the related answer. I'll experiment further with the 'Rust API exposing trait objects only' variant.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you gotta manually compile with rustc

```
rustc main.rs —-extern custom1=path/to/libcustom1.rlib —-extern custom2=path/to/libcustom2.rlib
```

With every library in the form of .rlib you add ‘—-extern’ for every single one of ‘em.

Refer to [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/crates/lib.html)

And to [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/crates/link.html)

More than that, the man page for rustc will give you extra leg on more complex things like FFI

Comment: IF you have a project called my_lib, this is also possible in Cargo.toml: [dependencies]
my_lib = {path = "../my_lib"} from your source project.