# How to build a dependency with a different version of the Rust compiler?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I've got a Rust project I build with the 1.33 tool chain. I need to add a dependency on a crate that can only be built with Rust nightly, how can I specify in the dependencies it should be built with nightly?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. Rust does not have a stable ABI and it is not possible to mix crates built with different versions of the compiler within the same project. [As of 2019, there is no plan to stabilize the ABI.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/600#issuecomment-499561636)

You must compile the entire project using a nightly compiler which you can do using [rustup](https://rustup.rs/).

Comment: What if I build the new crate with the nightly, can I take the resultant .rlib and link it to my main project?

Comment: @WiredWolf if your main project isn't using the same version of the compiler, then no.

Comment: You mean, if I get say a prebuilt, proprietary rust library from someone it had to be compiled with the same version of the tool chain I'm using in order for me to use it?

Comment: Yes. This is not as weird as it seems. [Visual Studio C++ used to do the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Compatibility) (and in fact Microsoft still has made no promises about ABI stability that I know about, they just happen to not have changed their ABI since VSC++ 2015). Maybe one day Rust will have a stable ABI and solve these problems but for now, the compiler is allowed to change anything between versions.

Comment: See also [Can libraries be distributed as a binary, so the end user cannot see the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27999559/155423); [How to statically link to an existing rlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50731453/155423)

Comment: So just to be clear (before starting working on it) my only route is to build a .dll (on Windows) of this new crate, and add some C wrapper that exposes whatever functionality I need from it, then use it in Rust with 'extern "C"' ?

Comment: But *why* do you need a nightly-only crate in an otherwise non-nightly project? There aren't that many things that require nightly nowadays except for some sugar whose benefit you'd definitely lose if you make a C wrapper.

Comment: I need this https://crates.io/crates/parquet any suggestions on how to integrate it into my project (assuming I don't want to transition to building my whole project with nightly)

Comment: @mcarton so given my use-case (previous comment) what are my options?

Comment: They only use specialization, have you looked into the code to see if the specialization is indeed necessary? (At least one use is not: it specializes a `Debug` implementation to be nicer in some cases.) It probably will be easier to remove the use of specialization or to feature-gate it.

Comment: I see them using a bunch of features, everything under #![feature requires nightly doesn't it?
`#![feature(
    repr_simd,
    const_fn,
    platform_intrinsics,
    stdsimd,
    aarch64_target_feature,
    arm_target_feature,
    link_llvm_intrinsics,
    core_intrinsics,
    stmt_expr_attributes,
    align_offset,
    mmx_target_feature,
    crate_visibility_modifier,
    custom_inner_attributes
)]`

Comment: Where did you find that? https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/rust/datafusion/src/lib.rs https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/rust/parquet/src/lib.rs#L18 https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/rust/arrow/src/lib.rs#L24

Comment: It's from an (indirect) dependency of Parquet: packed_simd-0.3.3

Comment: They have a bunch of [`/* SIMD implementation if available */ #[cfg(any(target_arch = "x86", target_arch = "x86_64"))]` in their code](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/c48bc1a6b1c9e11d76d1dd4d3cdf23544b716237/rust/arrow/src/buffer.rs#L221-L241). Wouldn't be too hard to feature-gate all of these given that they already support non-SIMD alternatives.