# Link rlib file in bin crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am rust beginner.
I maked rlib file in bin crate.
And I would like to link this rlib file in bin crate without exporting source code.
Just like linking object file in C/C++.

By adding dependencies in cargo.toml, I think it is necessary to rebuild from.source.
How can I write Cargo.toml?

My rust edition is 2018. Please :)

Comment: [How to statically link to an existing rlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731453/how-to-statically-link-to-an-existing-rlib)
[Can libraries be distributed as a binary, so the end user cannot see the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999559/can-libraries-be-distributed-as-a-binary-so-the-end-user-cannot-see-the-source)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I visited your first link. I would like to link by cargo.

Comment: I would like to make single binary from source, external crate and rlib file.